# Event handling with winform component

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling

I have a class `StripButton` which inherits from `Label`. I have overriden the `onClick` method. The user of this class also assigns events to the `onClick eventhandler`. I have noticed that the overriden method gets fired last. I want the overriden method to fire first. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Click` handler of a StripButton on your Form will fire when the `base.OnClick` method in the `OnClick` handler is called in your UserControl.  So if you want your UserControl's `OnClick` code to run before the `Click` handler code runs on your Form, call `base.OnClick` last in your UserControl's `OnClick` handler.  Conversely, if you want your Form's `Click` code to run after your UserControl's `OnClick` code, call `base.OnClick` first in your UserControl's `OnClick` handler.

It's probably easiest to illustrate with the simplest example:

```
// Your UserControl.
class StripButton : Label
{
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("This runs before the Click handler on the parent form.");
        base.OnClick(e);
        Console.WriteLine("This runs after the Click handler on the parent form.");
    }
}

// On your form.
private void stripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("stripButton1_Click on form");
}
```

If you run this you'll see the following in the Output Window:

```
This runs before the Click handler on the parent form.
stripButton1_Click on form
This runs after the Click handler on the parent form.
```

Hopefully that answers your question.